# Vue.js, parent not responding to child event

Tags: javascript, events, vue.js, vue-component

I've got an issue where a parent component isn't responding to a child's event. Using the Vue Developer Tools, I can see that the `events_loading` event is being emitted by the `<Calendar>` component, but the parent just isn't responding.

The parent HTML is...

```
<div class="appContainer" v-on:events_loaded="test" v-bind:class="{ 'appContainer--isLoading':is_loading }">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <div class="appView" id="js-appView">
        <aside class="appAside">
            <date-picker></date-picker>
        </aside>
        <main class="appMain">
            <calendar></calendar>
        </main>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the JS is...

```
export default {
    name: 'app',
    methods: {
        test: function() {
            alert('sdfds');
        }
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            is_loading: false
        }
    },
    components: {
        'app-header': AppHeader,
        'date-picker': DatePicker,
        'calendar': Calendar
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to listen the event from the `calendar`, so you should write the `v-on` on the calendar component:

```
<calendar v-on:events_loaded="test"></calendar>
```

not on your parent component's container.